# Load chrome extension to chrome on automation process

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chromium

I'm using automation test to test my WebApp.
In my test, I want to test my chrome extension too.

When my automation start running, (I'm using selenium), how can I load the chrome extension to the chrome automation test window?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it via [DesiredCapabilities](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities) when you launch the browser. For Chrome, it's [desiredCapabilities.chromeOptions](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities).args, where you can add a `--load-extension` [command line switch](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) that points to your extension path:

```
  "desiredCapabilities": {
    ...
    "chromeOptions": {
      "args": [
        "--load-extension=path/to/extension",
        ...
```

Note that incognito and headless modes do not seem to allow extensions.